# matrix_stats is not present in elasticsearch-dsl library

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

While running this code

```
try:
    connections.create_connection(hosts=[ES_IP], timeout=ES_TIMEOUT, http_auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
    print "Connected to elasticsearch node "+ES_IP
    #logging.info("Connected to elasticsearch node "+ES_IP)
except:
    print "Connection refused by elasticsearch node "+ES_IP
    #logging.error("Connection refused by elasticsearch node "+ES_IP)
    return -1
else:
    s=Search(index = "*-indices-alias")
    a = A('matrix_stats',field=['ERABESTABADDATTNBRQCI1','ERABESTABADDATTNBRQCI6'])
    s.aggs.bucket('statistics',a)
    pprint(str(s.to_dict()))
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "elastic_query.py", line 45, in <module>
run_agg_dsl_query()
  File "elastic_query.py", line 41, in run_agg_dsl_query
    a = A('matrix_stats',field= 
['ERABESTABADDATTNBRQCI1','ERABESTABADDATTNBRQCI6'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/aggs.py", line 42, in A
    return Agg.get_dsl_class(name_or_agg)(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/utils.py", line 216, in get_dsl_class
     raise UnknownDslObject('DSL class `%s` does not exist in %s.' % (name, cls._type_name))
elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.UnknownDslObject: DSL class `matrix_stats` does not exist in agg.
```

If i replace "matrix_stats" with "terms" query is getting generated as

```
"{'query': {'match_all': {}}, 'aggs': {'statistics': {'terms': {'field': ['ERABESTABADDATTNBRQCI1', 'ERABESTABADDATTNBRQCI6']}}}}"
```

but i want query to be generated as

```
"{'query': {'match_all': {}}, 'aggs': {'statistics': {'matrix_stats': {'field': ['ERABESTABADDATTNBRQCI1', 'ERABESTABADDATTNBRQCI6']}}}}"
```

Is matrix_stats currently not supported by elasticsearch-DSL library?
if yes, can we expect to be added matrix aggregation in future?
if no, than what i am missing as i am new to this.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `dsl` doesn't yet support this aggregation, my apologies. To make it available you can always define it yourself by putting:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.aggs import Agg

class MatrixStats(Agg):
    name = 'matrix_stats'
```

Then it should work.